# overwriting basic count function in laravel globally

Tags: laravel, php-7, php-8

We are upgrading our laravel project, and it includes a language upgrade from php7 to php8. Consider this code:

```
$a = new stdClass()
count($a)
```

Will result in:

```
// php7
==> 1

// php8
==> TypeError  count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array
```

Now our app is pretty big, there are a *lot* of small bits and pieces to it, and count was used in many places on things that it probably shouldn't have been used. I covered most of the ground, but ideally I'd like to have some kind of fallback. Is there a way to globally override the built in count function within the laravel application, hopefully to do something like this :

```
// very general pseudocode
function newCount($foo) { 
    try {
        return count($foo); 
    } except {
        \Log::warning('used count on non Countable|array')
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Then bind it somehow so:

```
// anywhere in the app code
count($a) // ==> will call newCount($a) instead
```

Comment: nope ... but there is no reason you can't do a search and replace in your own code base to replace the calls with something else

Comment: Why not update the `count()` directly ? Then when it triggers the `TypeError` exception it need to return 1 ?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why did you write so strange code in the first place? Why not change the code to something that does what it should be design, and not randomly? Calling `count` on an object that does not implement Countable looks pretty weird to me

Comment: @NicoHaase I didn't. The codebase was written by several developers over a period of almost of a decade. Some of it is well written, some parts are strange. I'm the one trying to upgrade it. It is what it is.

Comment: @lagbox I already did that, but that's the thing, the codebase is big enough that I might be missing certain parts. That's why I still want to somehow "configure" a generalized fallback so some niche parts of the system that I might have missed won't error and fail to work. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You have a multiple approaches to achieve this, using some third-party extension, one approach will be using [uopz](https://github.com/krakjoe/uopz) which allow you to hook into a predefined function and edit it's behavior.

the other method is to use some static code analyzer - something like [PHPStan](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan) - or any other alternative, to scan & update your code easily.